# Promise function not running in suitelet script

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, exceljs

I'm trying to run this suitelet to export excel using `exceljs`. But I have this line, it runs through this promise function and I got stuck. Log 'ok2' is not showing in Execution Log. Any Idea for this? Thanks a lot!!!

```js
var buf = wb.xlsx.writeBuffer();
log.debug('ok', buf);
buf.then(function(buf) {
    log.debug('ok2');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create function `buf` outside your Suitelet `OnRequest` function and call it whenever you require i.e. whenever the condition gets true.

Something like -

```
function onRequest(scriptContext) {
   //Additional code
   var buf = wb.xlsx.writeBuffer();
   log.debug('ok', buf);

   if(buf) {
      //Calling function with parameters if any
      bufFunction();
}

function bufFunction() {
   //Your function
}
```

Let me know in case of any issues in comments below.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to mention that this writeBuffer is a Promise. Normally it is using like this: 

`const buffer = await workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer();` So at the time you check if (buf) it might not be available